# What is happening when calling an enum/enum class with parentheses in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, enums, enum-class

This is maybe a bit weird question, but I really don't know how to phrase it better than this.

I just discovered that I can do the following:

```
#include <iostream>

enum class Colour  // also works with plain old enum
{
    Red = 1,
    Green,
    Blue,
    Yellow,
    Black,
    White
};

int main()
{
    Colour c = Colour(15);  // this is the line I don't quite understand

    std::cout << static_cast<int>(c) << std::endl;  // this returns 15

    return 0;
}
```

So now I have integer value 15 in a variable of the type `Colour`.

What exactly is happening here? Is that some kind of enum "constructor" at work? As far as I know, integer value 15 is not put into enumeration, it is stored just in variable `c`. Why would something like that be useful, in the first place - to create a value that doesn't exist in enum?

Comment: It's just another way to write the C-style cast `(Colour)15`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Colour(15)` is an expression that creates a temporary *(prvalue)* instance of the `Colour` enum, initialized with the value `15`.

`Colour c = Colour(15);` initializes a new variable `c` of type `Colour` from the previously-explained expression. It is equivalent to `Colour c(15)`.

Answer (score 3):

What's happening here is that strongly-typed enums in C++11 are still capable of holding out-of-range values if you explicitly cast or default initialize them.  In your example `Colour c = Colour(15);` is perfectly valid even though `Colour` only has meaningful values for 1-6.

Comment: `Colour` only has **named** values for 1-6. That doesn't mean that other values are not meaningful, just that they don't have names. One common use for enums is to define bit masks: `enum mask { read = 1, write = 2, hidden = 4 };` Now `mask(read+write)` has the value 3, and means that whatever we're talking about can be read and written.