# Compilation fails on OpenBSD due to "invalid conversion from size_t to [enum]", works on Linux

Tags: android, c, adb, openbsd

The `adb` command on OpenBSD is outdated ([5.1.1.4](http://ports.su/devel/adb) vs the current version of [7.0.0](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic/+package/adb)). After [some adjustments](https://github.com/serv-inc/platform_system_core/tree/port-openbsd), and copying the Makefiles from the [launchpad package](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/android-platform-system-core/1:7.0.0+r33-2), compiling `liblog` failed with

```
liblog/config_read.c:38:62: error: invalid conversion from 'size_t {aka long unsinged int}' to 'log_id_t {aka log_id}' [-fpermissive]
    if (!transport->available || ((*transport->available)(i) >= 0)) {
```

`transport` [is a `struct` that contains](https://github.com/serv-inc/platform_system_core/blob/port-openbsd/liblog/logger.h#L66)

```
int (*available)(log_id_t logId);
```

where [`log_id_t` is an enum](https://github.com/serv-inc/platform_system_core/blob/port-openbsd/liblog/include/log/log_id.h#L26) and `i` is a `size_t`. Beyond [What is happening when calling an enum/enum class with parentheses in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47700057/what-is-happening-when-calling-an-enum-enum-class-with-parentheses-in-c):

- Why does this error occur?
- How can it be fixed?
- Or is there is an alternative for installing a current `adb` in OpenBSD?

Comment: I would add the cast myself if you do not want to amend the makefile

Comment: @P__J__: modifying the line to `... || ((int)(*transport->available)(i) >= 0)) {` failed to change things. As there are more instances than this single one, changing the Makefile would be best. Which change would fix it?

Comment: (*transport->available)(i) -> (*transport->available)((log_id_t)i)

Comment: @P__J__: that fixed that particular instance, thank you. Feel welcome to post an answer. (A way to change the Makefile would be even more welcome, `-fpermissive` did not change a thing).

Comment: @P__J__: it has been fixed by casting to log_id_t inside each loop iteration

Comment: Please, read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question, showing the complete code and the exact error you get and where you get it from.  You are most probably misunderstanding the error message and what is happening there.